# Firebase SDK Uncaught [object Object]

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, android-webview, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem trying to load a page with the Firebase SDK on an Android WebView. The page is on Firebase Hosting and when it tries to load the *firebase-auth* through:

`<script src="/__/firebase/4.1.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>`

it raises an error on *adb logcat*:

`I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(39)] "Uncaught [object Object]", source: https://<Project ID>/__/firebase/4.1.2/firebase-auth.js`

I have tried synchronizing this with the loading of */__/firebase/4.1.3/firebase-app.js*, but it didn't change anything. I also tried using the "standard" SDK and when *firebase.js* is loaded:

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>`

Nearly the same error appears on *adb logcat*:

`I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(69)] "Uncaught [object Object]", source: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js`

This doesn't show on Desktop Web Browsers and in the iOS WebView. As it seams this is stoping the load process of the page, thus the page appears incomplete to the user. Does anyone know how to solve this ?